# How to select duplicates from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Considering this example of a very large table named 'Customer':

```
CustomerID   | LastName | FirstName | Address | City |
-------------|----------|-----------|---------|------|
1520         | Guere    |Francisco  |XPTO     |London|**
2214         | Santos   |António    |TUDO     |Porto |
3998         | Freixe   |Luís       |IUPO     |Quebec|
1520         | Guere    |Francisco  |XPTO     |Rome  |**
5691         | Anton    |Ana        |TIDI     |Lisbon|
1520         | Guere    |Francisco  |XPTO     |Rome  |**
```

As you can see from this small example, for the same customer (`CustomerID = 1520`) there is different values in the City column.

For example, the desired output in this case would be:

```
 CustomerID | City |
 -----------|------|
 1520       |London|
 1520       |Rome  |
```

I tried to develop a query that return the CustomerID that have different values in the City column.

```
SELECT CustomerID, City 
FROM (SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(DISTINCT City) FROM Customer GROUP BY CustomerID) 
WHERE City > 1
```

Can someone help me on what's wrong with the query i developed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT CustomerID, City
FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerID IN (
  SELECT CustomerID
  FROM Customer
  GROUP BY CustomerID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT City) > 1
)
GROUP BY CustomerID, City;
```

Result:

```
| CustomerID | City   |
|------------|--------|
| 1520       | London |
| 1520       | Rome   |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` if you want the cities:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where exists (select 1
              from customers c2
              where c2.customerid = c.customerid and c2.city <> c.city
             );
```

Or you can use `group by`, if you just want the customers:

```
select customerid
from customers
group by customerid
having min(city) <> max(city);
```

Comment: @Anna . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  It should be much more efficient than an `in` with a `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `HAVING` to filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerID IN(SELECT CustomerID
                    FROM Customer 
                    GROUP BY CustomerID
                    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT City) > 1);
```